# Warning with qml.qrc while compiling Qt app for iOS

Tags: ios, qt

I'm getting started with Qt and put together a simple app.

While compiling for iOS (and only then), I get the warning:

> The file reference for "/Users/[path to my app]/qml.qrc" is a member
>   of multiple groups ("Supporting Files" and "Resources"); this
>   indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the
>   groups will be preserved (but membership in targets will be
>   unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than
>   one group, please add another reference to the same path.

I started occurring after I removed a prefix from the qrc, but I can't find the reason why.

Comment: Is this error from qmake? I never came across the term "Supporting Files" while working with qmake. Could you add your project file to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I found the problem. My project file said:

RESOURCES +=  / 
qml.qrc

I deleted the / and now everything runs fine.